# how to access ajax variable out side from the ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var items;

             $.ajax({
                url: 'item/getProducts',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                items=data;
                console.log(data); //this code work and show the data
                }
            });
    console.log(items);// display undefined 

});
```

i'm trying to access items variable out side of the ajax block .but when i console it it display undefined 
how can i access items variable ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a JS `function` which takes variable `items` as the param & write whatever you want to do in it.

Call this function inside the `success callback` of your Ajax call under the `items=data` or else you will have to write all the logic inside the ajax success callback itself.

`async:false` can give you the items variable where you are expecting it right now but since it becomes a **synchronous ajax request which may not be good for user's experience & might give impression of browser freeze** if the call takes long time.

e.g:

```
<script>
function handleJSON(jsonData){
    console.log(jsonData); //wat you needed is here.

   // whatever your logic here.
}
$(document).ready(function() {

        var items;

         $.ajax({
            url: 'item/getProducts',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
            items=data;
            handleJSON(items); // or pass the data directly here.
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you may want to consult jQuery Promises also

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 3):

Your call `$.ajax()` is async you can't access the result directly after the call.

Thats why you should use the callback function. What are you trying to achieve ?

One solution can be to use ajax with `async:false` parameter (not recommended).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var items;

         $.ajax({
            url: 'item/getProducts',
            dataType: 'json',
            async : false,
            success: function(data){
            items=data;
            console.log(data); //this code work and show the data
            }
        });

        console.log(items);// display undefined 
});
```

Comment: i'm trying to add values into a select box @Quentin Roger

Comment: You should add your items in the `success` callback so.

Comment: async:false will give you browser freeze if request takes long.

Comment: why not to add values to your select using a simple loop inside the success callback if it is the only required thing? @sasy

Answer (score 1):

It happens because JavaScript is single threaded and JQuery ajax() method is asynchronous.

After making an AJAX call JavaScript engine will not wait for response to come back. So JavaScript engine will execute `console.log(items);` .It gives undefined because at the time it execute `console.log(items);`, `item` variable is not set to result from AJAX request.

Notice that `undefined` is printed in console before print the data from AJAX request.

You can tell JavaScript engine to wait for the response from server by adding `async : false` parameter to AJAX call.